# Download a file checked into github into Jenkins workspace using pipeline script

Tags: bash, shell, github, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to download a file which is checked into github into Jenkins workspace. But its throwing error saying 'failed writing body (0 != 1364)'. how can download a file from github to jenkins workspace? Appreciate any solution on this?

```
stage('Download github file ')
{
 steps{
    script{
        sh'''
         curl -H github-ssh-key -o $WORKSPACE -L 'https://github.com/<repo>/blob/1.2.0/test.csv'
      '''               
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Is there some particular reason you are trying to download a particular file rather than just clone the repo?

Comment: Hi @johnfo i just want to avoid to download more larger files into workspace to save some memory. Is this possible to download single file from github or could you please let me know how can we clone entire repo into Jenkins workspace ?

Comment: I sometimes do things by going to the file on the web UI, choose the version I want and then say "raw". Then use the URL shown the the browser. I've never used it, though, when the repo was not public and I somehow needed to use credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Groovy code, you can use to download a specific file from a Private repo. First, you need to generate a GitHub access token that can be used.

```
def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def get = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/something/hosts").openConnection();
get.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic " + accessToken)
def content = get.getInputStream().getText()
```